# Spring Webflux vs Async

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, nonblocking, spring-async

I'm a bit confused about how Webflux is different from Springs @Async. Some pages say that Springs Async Model is blocking, and Webflux is non-blocking. Other pages state that Springs Async is indeed non-blocking.
I thought that async can't be blocking, why would I use it if it was?
What is the benefit of using webflux over async?

Answer (score 0):

***DIFFERENCES***

- Spring Async I/O model during its communication with the client is blocking. It may cause a performance problem with slow clients. On the other hand, Spring WebFlux provides a non-blocking I/O model.
- Reading the request body or request parts is blocking in Spring Async, whiles it is non-blocking in Spring WebFlux.
- In Spring Async, Filters and Servlets are working synchronously, but Spring WebFlux supports full asynchronous communication.

Do all of these items lead us to use Spring WebFlux? Well, Spring Async or even Spring MVC might be the right answer to a lot of projects out there, depending on the desired load scalability or availability of the system.

Regarding scalability, Spring Async gives us better results than synchronous Spring MVC implementation. Spring WebFlux, because of its reactive nature, provides us elasticity and higher availability.

Source: [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-async-vs-webflux)

The Baeldung web provides a lot of information about Spring, I recommend that you use it regularly, it usually has what you are looking for

Comment: A lot of information provided be baeldung is faulty. The best source of documentation is always the official spring documentation